# Creating form from Django user model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to build a form for registering a user - using Django's built in user model and using generic views. I can't figure out how to confirm a password.

```
<form action="."  method="post">
{% csrf_token  %}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <p>
        {{ form.username.errors }}
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        {{ form.username }}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ form.email.errors }}
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        {{ form.email }}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ form.password.errors }}
        {{ form.password.label_tag }}
        {{ form.password }}
    </p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

So my problems are that it doesn't submit and I can't confirm the password. The password is also plain text instead of hidden but I'll fix that later.

I tried form.password_confirmation and form.confirm_password but they don't work. Can't find this documented anywhere.

Comment: I got it working with form.as_p which gave all the database fields (even ones I wouldn't want). So.. it's a problem with my form. Do other people register users this way?

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to django-registration to register users. It is a very complete, reusable app for that purpose. I use it and I'm quite happy with it.

http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration

You have the full sources to check how it solves the password confirmation issue, etc.

This may not directly answer your question, but it will probably solve your registration needs and allow you to focus your coding energies elsewhere.

Comment: I easy_install'd it but it didn't generate any new files. Is it meant to?

Comment: django-registration gets installed with your Python site-packages. That's where the new files will be installed. You might try including the (r'^userregurl/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')) in the relevant urls.py file. Not sure if it works with the easy_install version or not.

Comment: chenck the quick start guide, it's pretty straightforward: http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/quickstart.html - I got it running and complete with templates for web pages and emails in a couple of hours a.f.a.i.r.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean this form: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.3/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L10 - in which case you should have two password fields: `password1` and `password2` (so it's strange that `password` works for you and produces plain text field...). But, as Carles Barrobés suggested, you better give a try to [django-registration](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration).

Comment: Hmm neither form.password1 or form.password2 will work for me